# Completion of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space.

Then, to complete the space, Rudin in his book Real and Complex Analysis considers $\Sigma ^\star$, the collection of all $E\subset X$ for which there exist sets $A$ and $B\in \Sigma$ such that $A\subset E\subset B$ and $\mu(B-A) = 0$, and define $\mu(E)=\mu(A)$.

But, I am thinking that wouldn't it be more "natural" to consider $\overline \Sigma$ = $\Sigma \cup C$, where $C$ is the collection of all subsets of a measure zero set?

Comment: But that wouldn't be a $\sigma$-algebra. Note that you can also write $\Sigma^\ast$ as $\Sigma^\ast = \bigl\{ A \cup N : A \in \Sigma, \bigl(\exists B\in \Sigma\bigr)\bigl(N \subset B \land \mu(B) = 0\bigr)\bigr\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer If I generate the smallest $\sigma$ algebra using $\overline \Sigma $, then would the generated $\sigma$ algebra be equal to $\Sigma ^\star$?

Comment: Yes, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\overline{\Sigma}$ is $\Sigma^\ast$.